# How to find the smallest-area ellipse circumscribing a convex polygon?

Tags: geometry, algorithm

We are currently dealing with the problem of:
**How to find an ellipse circumscribing a convex polygon?**
Recent googling and lots of reading could **not** help me so much :(
[image]

Comment: You mean how to find *the smallest* ellipse inscribing a convex polygon?

Comment: @julien Correct. Indeed the smallest and optimum ellipse inscribing a convex polygon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An algorithm for your problem is described [here](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/inst/pubs/tr-b-98-05.abstract.html). You may be interested by [its implementation in CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Bounding_volumes_ref/Class_Min_ellipse_2.html).

Comment: +1.  Note that the solution does not require the polygon to be convex.